# Finding max and min of a data set in a textfile; Fun Puzzle

Tags: python

In a data set, I need to print the smallest number over the integer size of 100. 
However, I have been trying `min()` but this has not been working. The question in whole says,

> "Write a Python program which reads in the carbon emissions data from
>   carbon-emissions.txt and performs the following three calculations,
>   each computing an aggregate combining data from all the years in which
>   more than 100 million tonnes of carbon was emitted:
>
> - Minimum carbon dioxide emissions among these years
> - Maximum carbon dioxide emissions among these years
> - Total sum of the carbon dioxide emissions among these years
>
> Your program should output the values in terms of million tonnes of
>   carbon dioxide, rather than carbon. One tonne of carbon is equivalent
>   to 3.67 tonnes of carbon dioxide, so you can multiply by 3.67 to
>   perform the conversion. You can do the conversion to carbon dioxide
>   either before or after the aggregations"

So far what I have done is:

```
for value in open("carbon-emissions.txt"): 
  value_float = float(value)
  if int(value_float) > 100:
    print(value_float)
```

Where it converts the entire data set into float, and then tries to find the numbers larger than 100, however this prints everything over 100.

I think after I will have ascribed a max value, a min value, and all the values over 100 summed together. Once I do that I would print:

```
print("Minimum Co2 emissions:" + int(min_value)*3.67)
print("Maximum Co2 emissions:" + int(max_value)*3.67)
print("Total Co2 emissions:" + int(sum_value)*3.67)
```

The program should come out as:

```
Minimum Co2 emissions: 381.68
Maximum Co2 emissions: 36167.85
Total Co2 emissions: 1467460.51
```

EDIT:
The code for max is this:

```
max_sofar = 0
for value in open("carbon-emissions.txt"):
    value_float = float(value)
    max_sofar = max(max_sofar, value_float)

print("Maximum Co2 emissions:", max_sofar*3.67)
```

However, I can't seem to find the minimum. I need to make it larger than 100 , yet I need to find the minimum of those set of numbers.

Comment: I have resolved the maximum code bit. The code is:
max_sofar = 0
for value in open("carbon-emissions.txt"):
    value_float = float(value)
    max_sofar = max(max_sofar, value_float)
    
print("Maximum Co2 emissions:", max_sofar*3.67)

Comment: Your code should only be performing max, min, and sum calculations for data > 100. Your new max code doesn't do that. Burhan Khalid's answer is close, it just has a couple of errors.

Comment: Why `0` or `100` – or *any* random starting comparison value? Read the very first value and compare against that; all others will be larger or smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should all values to a list, and then run `min`, `max` and `sum` on it.

```
values = []
with open('carbon-emissions.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line.strip(): # skips empty lines
          value = float(line)
          if value > 100:
               values.append(value * 3.67)

print('The minimum value is: {0:.2f}'.format(min(values)))
print('The maximum value is: {0:.2f}'.format(max(values)))
print('The total is: {0:.2f}'.format(sum(values)))
```

Comment: File "program.py", line 10
    print('The maximum value is: {0:.2f}'.format(max(values)))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

comes out with this?

Comment: **1** A `list` doesn't have an `.add` method. **2** You are missing some closing parentheses.

Comment: @D.Ronald No worries. :)